# How can I change calender to Persian calender (like in KDE)?

Tags: 14.04, unity, calendar, date

If we set the language support and location in KDE for a special country like my country, Iran, it changes the calendar and date time format for that country usage.

Now I need to do the same in my Ubuntu 14.04. I've searched for it but onyl found a package `jcal` which is useable in CLI mode, or `jalali-calendar` which is for Ubuntu 10.04.

How to change the Ubuntu calendar to Persian calendar?

Comment: There are instructions to install a Jalali Calendar applet at the [Iranian Ubuntu Team Wiki](http://wiki.ubuntu-ir.org/JalaliCalendarApplet). Have you tried it on Unity?

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately, It's very simple. Just configure the calendar from `System Settings/Locale` to **Jalali**.
[image: Jalali Calendar in System Settings/Locale]

Of course I've tested this in Slackware. Slackware is complete in many aspects. Maybe you need install some packages in order to have Jalai calendar in your list. It would be appreciated if you tell if installing other packages is required.